# Drupal 7.x: Using Google Maps JS in a custom module for complex map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a Google Maps script that I had to custom create because it has several polygons, event listeners, markers, and infowindows, and from what I read, the Google Maps API module can't handle things that are that complicated. I tried using the gmap module to make a map, and I was able to do that, but I was not able to do all the things I wanted to, so I turned to using JS.

Now, I would like this script to populate on either a node that I can promote on the front page, or directly on the front page, but nowhere else. I've searched the internet for how to do this, and most tutorials on adding custom JS onto Drupal have to do with theming, and all the tutorials I have followed on creating a custom module don't work for me.

How can I accomplish what I'm looking to do? Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish these using "Google map field" where you can add google map field to add any content type and created node.

You can also do using custom module,where you have to created simple menu_callback function and add external javascript using drupal_add_jsin that you can used any google-api library.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to add another module if I can avoid it because of how complex the JS code is.  Also, I did already make a custom module using drupal_add_js() but for some reason it isn't working... I need a sound step-by-step of how to put a JS Google Map on a node or front page

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Absolutely forgot to reference a div in which the JS would load. Was able to just use drupal_add_js() in the node, then by declaring the div container, it just popped up!